# Count values in a mysql field

Tags: mysql, count, field

I have a mysql table like this with currencies stored in database via checkboxes and php

```
product       currencies
-----------   --------------
prod_name_1   *usd*cad*euro*
prod_name_2   *usd*cad*
prod_name_3   *usd*cad*euro
prod_name_4   
prod_name_5   *usd*
```

I want to count currencies in a field with a query.
Expected results:

```
product       currencies count
-----------   ----------------
prod_name_1   3
prod_name_2   2
prod_name_3   3
prod_name_4   0
prod_name_5   1
```

How can i query my db in order to get this result?
I tried many functions (including COUNT and SUM) with many conditionals but nothing works.
Any help will be VERY appreciated!

Thanks to all!

Comment: This is not a normalized design.

Answer (score 1):

You need a string manipulation function to count distinct currencies given your NON-NF1 data.

Try something like this:

```
select product,
       CAST((LENGTH(currencies) - LENGTH(REPLACE(currencies, '*', ''))) / LENGTH('*') AS UNSIGNED) AS currencies_count
  from YOUR_TABLE
```

The thing is, you will need to represent your data in a coherent manner. I.E.:

```
*usd*cad*euro
```

Must be always represented this way **and not**:

```
*usd*cad*euro*
```

Otherwise, you will count more currencies than you have.

Comment: Thanks to all for all replies! Yes, I know I have to represent data in this manner (*usd*cad*euro) but I can't. I use an external component (in joomla) that store data in this way. There is a method to ignore (in count) the empty space after '*' separator (last value)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a field to store multiple fields, so MySQL doesn't have a split function.

Instead, create another table with 2 fields (product id and currency id). You could count your currencies for your products with a join (`SELECT p.product_name, COUNT(c.currency_) FROM products p JOIN productconcurrencies c ON p.product_id=c.product_id`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend storing your data differently (if possible).
If you store it like this:

```
product      currencies
-----------------------
prod_name_1  usd
prod_name_1  cad
prod_name_1  euro
```

Then you can easily do a simple sql `count where product='prod_name_1'` (exact query up to you, of course).
**Edit**: As tstenner pointed out, you should use a separate table for your currencies and use a foreign key to that. My example is just the logical representation.

If that is not an option, like @Pablo Santa Cruz said in his answer you'll need to do some string manipulation. You could do this on the db side or the client side if it's just for display (might be easier as you'll probably have better string manipulation libraries).
Essentially you'll want to split your `currencies` string on the `*` character so you get an array similar to `["usd", "cad", "euro"]`. Then you can display it as you want.